# ClickOnce data files are not installing in users AppData folder

Tags: msbuild, .net-4.0, .net-4.5, visual-studio-2017, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce program that we have been using successfully for a couple of years. Recently, we decided to move the project to a Bamboo build server and as part of that move, we made two significant changes;

1. We updated the target framework from .NET Framework 4.0 to .NET Framework 4.5.2.
2. We are using powershell scripts to call msbuild for the build and publish stages, which are running as tasks in the Bamboo build plan

Now, when we install the program on a client computer, it does not copy any of the project's data files over to the user's  c:\users{username}\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\Data...

The files are listed in the projects publish tab --> Application Files section as Publish Status: Include (auto), Download Group: Required, Hash: Include

If I open and examine the manifest file generated for the project after the publish script runs, I can see the files referenced, for example...

```
  <file name="Data\MyFiles.zip" size="71341">
    <hash>
      <dsig:Transforms>
        <dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:HashTransforms.Identity" />
      </dsig:Transforms>
      <dsig:DigestMethod 
Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha256" />
      <dsig:DigestValue>NvXXXXR/TNpKPCVXXXXJ44v+vLIZhNZXXXXXXXXVk=
</dsig:DigestValue>
    </hash>
  </file>
```

But after the insatall, when I go to c:\users{username}\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\Data... there are no files.

Of course, the solution builds with no errors or warnings and the build and publish scripts run without errors. Also, no errors are generated when the ClickOnce application is installed on the client computer.

Also, I am not sure how this would apply, but when I converted the project from .NET Framework 4.0 to .NET Framework 4.5.2, a number of compiler errors were generated on the rebuild solution call that required that I put the word "System" in front of the reference, for example, changing...

```
Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes
```

To...

```
Case System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes
```

The client desktop that I am testing the install on is a Windows 10 Enterprise 64 Bit. I was able to install the older version of the ClickOnce program on this same computer and the data files were copied over to the AppData location with no problem.

I tested the project by doing a build and publish using the Visual Studio "Rebuild Solution" from right-click on the Solution an "Publish" from right-click on the project, rather than running the Powershell scripts and I still have the same problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ClickOnce data files are not installing in users AppData folder

If you want data file are installing in users appdata folder, you should change the **Publish Status** of the files from `Include (auto)` to `Data File`.

[image]

[image]